# The latest TypeScript in IntelliJ IDEA 13

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript

Can I update the TypeScript syntax highlighter in IntelliJ IDEA 13, to recognize the latest TypeScript? (without installing the latest IDEA)

Comment: Why? What's wrong with it? Is the plugin not updating? If so, you might have to upgrade Intellij

Comment: I think it has built-in TS support, it's not a plugin

Comment: It's part of the Javascript support plugin, that, yes, comes installed with Intellij, but it's not clear what you mean by highlighter. Like syntax highlighting? Again, bringing me back to, what is wrong with it?

Comment: Yes, the syntax highlighter, it supports old TypeScript (e.g. no namespaces, no string templates)